# Two conditions of while True loop

Tags: python

I want to write a `while True` loop which can only break if and only if the number a user input:

- is an integer
- the number is either 1 or 2

I wrote like this but somehow it not work

```
while True:
    s1=input("Choose the item you want to buy (1 and/or 2 only): ")
    try:
        a=int(s1)
        3>a>0
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually *check* the value:

```
if 0 < a < 3:
    break
```

You could also do:

```
if a in range(1, 3): # or if a in [1, 2]:
    break
```

However, it is worth mentioning that the less you have in the `try` block the better; you can end up hiding errors from yourself. Therefore a better structure might be:

```
try:
    a = int(s1)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    if 0 < a < 3:
        break
```

Comment: I want the loop keep repeating until it meet those two conditions

Comment: Yes, you put this inside your existing `while` loop